# How to run presentViewController in IOS static library

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I am trying to build static library for Camera in iOS, but it is showing error like this in my user application

```
Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x17e2f740> on <Camera: 0x17d3f5b0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I am using this code in Camera.m inside my static library libCamera.a like this

```
 -(void)callCamera
 {
  UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  picker.delegate = self;
  picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES];// Error is for this line
 }
```

I am using this library in my application checkcamera.m by importing libCamera.a

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
  [super viewDidLoad]
  Camera cam=[[Camera alloc]init];
  [cam callCamera]
  }
```

but it is showing above mentioned error, so i want to know how to run presentViewController inside static library?

Comment: [self performSelector:@selector(presentImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.33]; in presentImage method put your code..

Comment: @TamilKing still it is showing same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move `[cam callCamera]` from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear`. According to [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidAppear%3a) `viewDidAppear` is exact method that indicates your view controller's view is added to the window hierarchy.

EDITED:

If `Camera` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, please try this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    Camera *cam=[[Camera alloc] init];

    [self.view addSubview:cam.view];
    [self addChildViewController:cam];
    [cam callCamera];
}
```

Comment: I have edited my answer with a new solution, hope it will be helful

Comment: Thanks it worked..!, is there any way to modify code in library method, instead of changing in client application?

Comment: You are welcome! You can specify a method in Camera class, something like -(void)showOnViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController and place addSubview/addChildViewController calls there. Note, your root view controller (in which viewDidAppear we call camera) still should be added to window hierarchy (last point is iOS SDK requirement, can't be moved to lib)